# getting params from form_tag for datetime_local_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

so i am working with google calendar apis in rails.

```
 <%= form_tag new_event_url do %>
<div>
  Subject :
  <%= text_field_tag (:subject) %> 
  </div> <br>
  <div>
    Date And Time : 
    <%= datetime_local_field(:user, :event_date) %>
  </div><br>
```

i need to grab parameter from the datetime_local_field.
controller code:

```
  @subject = params[:subject]
  @date = params[:user_event_date]
  event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
  start: {

  date_time: @date.to_datetime.rfc3339
  },
  end: {
  date_time: @date.to_datetime.rfc3339
  },

  summary: @subject,
 })
```

the subject part is good, but can't get the date_time
how to access that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime_local_field` creates a nested input:

```
@date = params[:user][:event_date]
```

Next time just look at the log or do `params.inspect`.